# Looking for a shorthand JS way to evaluate the presence of multiple object / object states and set as a bool

Tags: javascript, if-statement

So i have a lot of states I need to set based on multiple objects presence and states:

At the moment I'm just doing a classic if statement and then checking against undefined.

```
let show_x = false;

if (some_object_presence !== 'undefined' || some_other_object_presence !== 'undefined' || some.other.object_presence !== 'undefined' ) {
    show_x = true;
}
...
```

This seems like a really long way to do it. Is there a shorthand version I can set like this:

```
let show_y = some_object_presence || some_other_object_presence || some.other.object_presence;
```

I need the state of show_y to be a boolean value. I did think about creating intermediate tests for each of the object states I'm looking for but that might just make it complicated again eg.

```
let some_object_presence = object_qwe ? true : false;
let some_other_object_presence = object_asd ? true : false;
let some_third_object_presence = object_zxc ? true : false;

let show_z = some_object_presence || some_other_object_presence || some_third_object_presence;
```

Any ideas would be helpful

Comment: your `'undefined'` is a string. do you really want check against a string value? please add some possible content of the variables.

Comment: Sorry that's my quickly typed out example but nice catch! :) The variables are all objects, although there may be scope to check for length of arrays and maybe other bools down the line... But at the moment just objects!

Answer (score 1):

You can just cast it to boolean with double negation.
If any of your objects are defined it is considered as true, so you might just let show_z as your object.

```
let show_z = !!(some_object_presence || some_other_object_presence || some_third_object_presence);
```

Not entirely correct but in short you can consider:
Empty strings `""`, 0 `0`, empty array `[]` and undefined variables `var x` as false. Everything else can be considered as true.

Comment: Didn't know you could do that! Very interesting!